# How to sort a dictionary by value and by key?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary where the keys are strings and the values are integers. I have to return a list which has the keys with smaller values first. In case of a tie, the key which comes first lexicographically is to be returned.

For example, consider a dictionary which maps names to weights.

```
    d={'Tony':78,'Steve':88,'Bruce':68,'Thor':78,'Bob':50}
```

Then the resultant list should be:

```
    ['Bob','Bruce','Thor','Tony','Steve']
```

Since Thor comes before Tony, lexicographically.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)`(`[`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)`(k, v): k,`[`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)`(list(d.`[`items()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)`), key=lambda (k,v): (v, k)))`, heh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to break the tie by name, first sort by value then key:

```
 from operator import itemgetter

 print(list(map(itemgetter(0), sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1,0)))))
 ['Bob', 'Bruce', 'Thor', 'Tony', 'Steve']
```

Or a regular list comp:

```
print([k for k,_  in sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1, 0))])
```

Answer (score 0):

Fairly easy:

```
result = sorted(d, key=lambda k: (d[k], k))
```

If the `dict` is huge, it might be worth avoiding the per-key `dict` lookup by iterating the items directly and using `itemgetter` to flip keys and values for sorting, then remove values in the result:

```
from operator import itemgetter

results = list(map(itemgetter(0), sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1, 0))))
```

Comment: Realized after I posted that the goal was sorting by value first, then key, so I edited to use both.